# SVN Authorization

Tags: svn, authorization

I am trying to setup SVN authorization (authentication works fine already) and my AuthzSVNAccessFile looks like the following:

```
[groups]
todos = user1, user2
proj = user1

[/]
@todos = r

[/myproj]
@proj = rw
```

However, I can checkout the content of proj (as user1) but I can't commit to it... If i change the file changing to the following:

```
[groups]
todos = user1, user2
proj = user1

[/]
@todos = rw

[/myproj]
@proj = rw
```

I can successful commit... What's wrong with my access file?
I am using SVN with SVNParentPath, to point to a folder containing multiple repositories.

The errors it gives are:

```
svn: Error: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to CHE
CKOUT
```

Comment: So, is the project called proj or myproj?

Comment: Checkout the content of what? You say "proj", but that is a user group.

Comment: proj is the name of the user group and myproj is the name of the project repository!

Comment: Checkout the content of myproj I can checkout successful but it gives this message when I try to commit (no idea why it says checkout, as I'm trying to commit) using the first configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the naming of the repositories. As project 1 repository was named myproj1 I needed to set up as:

```
[groups]
all = user1, user2
proj1users = user1

[/]
@all = r

[myproj1:/]
@proj1users = rw
@all =
```

so it would work giving the right permissions to the project1!